# Comparing original values to that which has least squares calculated on

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I currently have created a 3x3 grid of points, in `POINTS` which have a z value in `READINGS` which are correlated based on position in the array.

After I calculate least squares, I want to compare the difference between the z value of the plane of best fit, calculated by least squares to the original readings, but only in the same position. Is there any way I can do this?

```
import numpy as np
# import scipy.linalg
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

READINGS = [10.668, 10.398, 9.829, 10.114, 10.608, 10.793, 11.127, 11.034, 10.691]

z = READINGS
x = [None] * 9
y = [None] * 9
POINTS = [[-19, 208], [121, 208], [261, 208],
              [261, 148], [121, 148], [-19, 148],
              [-19, 58], [121, 58], [261, 58]]

for i in range(0, 9):
    x[i] = POINTS[i][0]
    y[i] = POINTS[i][1]

data = np.c_[x, y, z]
mn = np.min(data, axis=0)
mx = np.max(data, axis=0)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(mn[0], mx[0], 20), np.linspace(mn[1], mx[1], 20))
XX = X.flatten()
YY = Y.flatten()
# best-fit linear plane (1st-order)
A = np.c_[data[:, 0], data[:, 1], np.ones(data.shape[0])]
C, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:, 2], rcond=None)  # coefficients
# evaluate it on grid
Z = C[0] * X + C[1] * Y + C[2]
```

Comment: If I understand you want: `diff = A.dot(C) - data[:,2]`. Where `A.dot(C)` represent the estimated Z value, using a simple matrix multiplication.

Comment: @obchardon Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Noticed that `Z = C[0] * np.array(x) + C[1] * np.array(y) + C[2]` will produce the same result, but since we try to solve an `A*x = b` linear system of equation, it is IMO better to use `A.dot(x)` in order to compute b̂.